# Could we init the CIpher different for ENCRYPT_MODE and DECRYPT_MODE

Tags: android, encryption

I am kind of new to the encryption and decryption stuff. And I find it is really hard to find a good material or tutorial about it. And I went through the questions related to it in StackOverflow, didn't find a good answer for mine.

Here is my problem, if I want to encryption and decryption with transformation:

> "AES/GCM/NoPadding"

Could I do something below:

```
public DaoEncryptionResult<byte[]> getEncryptionResult(final ByteBuffer bufferToEncrypt) {
    try {
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        final SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(BinaryKey, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, mSecureRandom);
        final byte[] bytesToEncrypt = bufferToEncrypt.array();
        final byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(bytesToEncrypt,
                bufferToEncrypt.arrayOffset(), bufferToEncrypt.limit());
        final byte[] iv = cipher.getIV();
        return new DaoEncryptionResult<>(cipherText, iv);
    } catch (final GeneralSecurityException securityException) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not encrypt data", securityException);
    }
}

public byte[] getDecryptionResult(final byte[] encodedData, final byte[] encodedIv) {
    try {
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        final SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(BinaryKey, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(encodedIv));
        return cipher.doFinal(encodedData);
    } catch (final GeneralSecurityException securityException) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not decrypt data", securityException);
    }
}
```

mSecureRandom is intialized once during the whole application lifecycle by calling

> new SecureRandom()

BinaryKey is a byte[] which is decoded by Base64 from String with Base64.DEFAULT

The encodedData and encodedIv will be the same as the result returned in getEncryptionResult method.

By doing this, I always find some exception related to the decryption issue. For example:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: mac check in GCM failed
   at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(BaseBlockCipher.java:854)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1340)
   at com.amazon.rabbit.android.data.dao.DaoEncryptionManagerImpl.getDecryptionResult(DaoEncryptionManagerImpl.java:250)
```

Comment: BTW, if anyone knows a good material about this encryption and decryption stuff, could you share the link or name here?

Comment: Do you experience any problems with this code? What is your question exactly?

Comment: I have updated the exceptions I have find.

Answer (score 0):

Provided as an answer due to length and formatting, answering the comment: (good material about this encryption and decryption stuff, could you share the link)

There are books:

A free PDF of the book: [*Handbook of Applied Cryptography*](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/index.html) by Alfred J. Menezes, Paul C. van Oorschot and Scott A. Vanstone, see free download. Chapter is a reasonable start for current ciphers.

[*Cryptography Decrypted*](http://www.informit.com/store/cryptography-decrypted-9780201616477) by H. X. Mel and Doris M. Baker (good starter I really like)

[*Applied Cryptography*](https://www.schneier.com/books/applied_cryptography/) by Bruce Schneier

[*Cryptography Engineering*](https://www.schneier.com/books/cryptography_engineering/) by Niels Ferguson, Bruce Schneier, and Tadayoshi Kohno

There are also some good free courses in the web as [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/courses?languages=en&query=cryptography) and [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/applied-cryptography--cs387).